# Set initial Redux Store in Next getInitialProps or getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

I'm currently building a Next.js application where I'm attempting to set the initial Redux store with a user and team object. It works as I have implemented it, but now I'm trying to avoid making multiple requests to the backend API. I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to achieve this, and I'm also very concerned about whether my current approach follows best practices.

here is my _app.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { getUserApi } from '../lib/api/public';
import { getInitialData } from '../lib/api/team-member';
import { createReduxStore } from '../lib/store/redux_store/store';
import './_base.scss';
import { NextPage, NextPageContext } from 'next';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

type Props = {
  Component: NextPage;
  pageProps: any;
  initialState: any;
};

function App({ Component, pageProps, initialState }: Props) {
  const reduxStore = createReduxStore(initialState);
  const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href={isServer ? '/fonts/server.css' : '/fonts/cdn.css'} />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
      </Head>
      <Provider store={reduxStore}>
       <Component {...pageProps} intialState={initialState} store={store} />
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

App.getInitialProps = async ({
  Component,
  ctx,
}: {
  Component: NextPage;
  ctx: NextPageContext;
}) => {

  if (
    ctx.pathname.includes('/login') ||
    ctx.pathname.includes('/invitation')
  ) {
    
  }

  if (
    ctx.pathname.includes('/my-settings') ||
    ctx.pathname.includes('/team-settings') ||
    ctx.pathname.includes('/billing')
  ) {
    teamRequired = true;
  }

  const { teamSlug, discussionSlug, redirectMessage } = ctx.query;

  const pageProps = {
    teamId,
    redirectMessage,
  };

  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    Object.assign(pageProps, await Component.getInitialProps(ctx));
  }

  const appProps = { pageProps };

  let userObj = null;
  try {
    const { user } = await getUser(ctx.req);

    userObj = user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  let initialData;

  if (userObj) {
    try {
      initialData = await getInitialData({
        request: ctx.req,
        data: { teamId },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      initialData = null;
    }
  }

  let selectedTeamId = '';

  if (teamSlug) {
    selectedTeamId = teamId as string;
  } else {
    selectedTeamId = userObj && userObj.defaultTeamId;
  }

  const team =
    initialData && initialData.teams && initialData.teams.find((t) => t.teamId === selectedTeamId);

  const initialState = {
    user: userObj,
    currentUrl: ctx.asPath,
    team,
    teamId,
    ...initialData,
  };

  return {
    ...appProps,

    initialState,
  };
};

export default App;
```

And here my store.ts

```
import { Action, AnyAction, configureStore, ThunkAction, ThunkDispatch } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import userReducer from './slices/userSlice';
import teamReducer from './slices/teamSlice';
import { setCurrentTeam } from './thunks/teamThunks';

export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  team: teamReducer,
});

function getInitialState(initialData: any): RootState {
  const { user, teams, team } = initialData || {};

  if (user && teams) {
    user.teams = teams;
  }

  return {
    user: user || userReducer(undefined, { type: '' }),
    team: team || teamReducer(undefined, { type: '' }),
    isInitialized: !!initialData,
  };
}

export function createReduxStore(initialData: any) {
  console.log('Store initialized');
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    preloadedState: getInitialState(initialData),
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(thunk),
  });

  store.dispatch(setCurrentTeam(initialData.team));
  return store;
}

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer> & {
  isInitialized: boolean;
};
export type AppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<RootState, unknown, AnyAction>;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

export const selectUser = (state: RootState) => state.user;
export const selectTeam = (state: RootState) => state.team;

// Custom hooks to use selectors
export const useUserSelector = () => useSelector(selectUser);
export const useTeamSelector = () => useSelector(selectTeam);
```